# VxWorks 6.6 on PowerPC Boot Sequence _sysInit() opcode bizarity

Tags: boot, bootloader, vxworks, powerpc

For a project I am working on,
Running on PowerPC MPC-8641d, VxWorks6.6.

I need to launch a VIP image from another VIP project.
Investigating the boot sequence it seems that the boot-loader is:
reading the binary header of the image,
copy the binary image (without the hdr) to `0x100000`
and jumps to `0x100000` (where _sysInit()) is located.

doing the same thing as the boot-loader, my CPU freeze at address `0x100004h`

reading the content of `0x100000` revealed the following dump:

```
48 44 01 FC   BA AD C0 DE   00 00 00 00   00 00 00 00  
00 00 00 00   00 00 00 00   00 00 00 00   00 00 00 00
...
...
00 00 00 00   00 00 00 00   00 00 00 00   00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00   00 00 00 00   00 00 00 00   00 00 00 00
```

well, `0x484401FC` looks like function prolog,
but, `0xBAADC0DE` must be a joke!

How does my VIP run by calling this address.
am i missing something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`0x484401FC` is `b 0x4401fc`, so it should be branching to `0x4401fc` and never executing the instruction at `0x100004` (unless it returns, but the branch doesn't set `LR` so it would have to return manually).

Comment: thanks, i'll check that sunday, that's helpful. thanks.